# python modules for scp/sftp with bandwidth limitation

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, bandwidth

What python modules are available that can enable bandwidth throttling when pulling data over scp/sftp, if any?

My objective here is to write a python script that will pull data over sftp or scp (sftp preferred) from a series of data centers? however, I need to enforce a bandwidth limitation as some of the servers I'll be pulling from have low bandwidth.

I've thought of maybe an rsync wrapper, but is there something else that can also give me the option of removing the file from the data center I've just retrieved?

Thanks,
--Rob

Answer (score 0):

[pyftpdlib](https://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/) supports bandwidth throttling and SSL.

[Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/) might also be an option

Comment: it doesn't look like pyftpdlib supports sftp/scp (port 22)

I did look at the Paramiko but I couldn't find where it says it supports bandwidth limitation.

Comment: pyftplib supports ftps (port 21) rather than sftp.  Is there no flexibility in your choice of protocol?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of SCP with the parameter **limit_bw** that allows you to control the bandwidth in kbps.

https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py/tree/master

```
 scp_con = SCPClient(self.ssh.get_transport(), limit_bw=10000)
```